# Phaser.js How to make the correct collision of irregular images, rather than the edge of the gap is also triggered by the collision too

Tags: phaser-framework

In Phaser.js, how do I make the correct collision of irregular images, rather than the edge of the gap is also triggered by the collision too. Can the collision occur at the edge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Arcade physics** and set a smaller body inside of the sprite. For example:

```
var sprite = game.add.sprite(50,100,'mysprite');
sprite.anchor.setTo(0.5,0.5);
game.physics.arcade.enable(sprite);

// set smaller body rectangle - body.setSize(width,height,offsetX,offsetY)
sprite.body.setSize(55,110,0,2);
```

[Official offset bounding box example](http://phaser.io/examples/v2/arcade-physics/offset-bounding-box).

You can also use **P2 physics** and load physics so that you can use [PhysicsEditor](https://www.codeandweb.com/physicseditor), but it's not free.

There is also [Physics Body Editor](http://www.aurelienribon.com/blog/projects/physics-body-editor/). This one is very easy and handy but it's not supported Phaser yet.

Comment: Can Phaser put the edge of a very accurate calculation?

Comment: yes it does if you use p2 physics with physics editor.

Answer (score 0):

Use the build-in P2 Physics engine and use custom shapes and polygons.

Answer (score 0):

sprite.body.setSize(width, height, center);
sprite.body.setOffset(x, y);

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.